# Bobby Fischer and the U.S

Tags: history, fischer

Why did Bobby Fischer despise the U.S and why did he get exiled? 
Wasn't he America's hero at one point?
I'm a big fan of his games.

Comment: a quick stroll through his wikiquote page reveals that maybe later in his life he wasn't all that stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not so much that Fischer *got exiled* as much as it was that he chose to exile himself (though yes, out of a certain necessity). He was [indicted by a U.S. court for ignoring sanctions](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/12/16/world/fischer-is-indicted-over-chess-match.html) against Yugoslavia when playing his 1992 rematch against Spassky in that country, and so Fischer chose to avoid returning to the U.S. rather than face prosecution and a potential 10-year prison sentence. As to the various reasons he might have despised his home country, I won't speculate myself, but [plenty has been written](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307463915) about Fischer's troubled later years elsewhere.